# Node JS - Elastic Beanstalk AWS - allow write access

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ebextensions

I have a NodeJS application i am deploying to AWS Elastic Beanstalk, which needs to be able to write to some JSON files which is in the applications directories.

This is currently working locally but not when i deploy to AWS because clearly write permissions are not there.

Can you please let me know what i need to add to EBEXTENSIONS and how, to allow write access with a NodeJS Elastic Beanstalk app

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't store anything important on AWS Elastic Beanstalk servers as they can get terminated/rolled-over depending on the requirement and **you will lose the files**.

AWS EB should **always be stateless**.

But if you want to write some temporary files, you already have permissions in the app directory.

But if you want to change permissions of some other directory, say `/var/log`

you can do this in `container_commands`

```
container_commands:
    change_permissions:
        command: chmod 750 /var/log
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for that :) - Fully aware about the stateless thing, but this is just to show a basic prototype to management about something not a production machine :)